# .net - Losing focus after creating an IE object

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, focus

I have an application which runs in the background and occasionally creates a hidden IE object. Whenever this object is created tho it causes the window I was viewing to lose focus. Is there a way to make it so whenever it creates an IE object it doesn't cause my current window to lose focus?

```
oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE.Visible = False
```

Comment: Can you give us more details on what you're trying to accomplish in your background process?  Maybe we can come up with a better way to avoid the problem in the first place, rather than calling CreateObject() and launching IE.

Comment: I think the OP would deserve a downvote for ignoring the crowd's input.

Comment: Sorry for not replying but I chose an answer so I thought the thread was closed. The program launches IE and navigates to certain webpages and executes some javascript. I ended up just dealing with the losing focus and the program works ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is being controlled by the OS... `CreateObject()` creates a COM object, which in this case is the full-blown IE app.  Behind the scenes, COM is calling into the object you're creating, which is launching a browser window.  There are no parameters you can pass to `CreateObject()`, because this call literally has no control over what the instantiated COM object does.

However, the OS has a setting to disable windows from stealing focus when they are launched... this is what you need.

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windowsxp/ht/stealingfocus02.htm - link with instructions to disable this.

If you're still using XP, you can download a tool called TweakUI that will let you set this.

HTH, 
James

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about windows foms, simply call [`Window.Activate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.activate.aspx) after setting the ie object to visible.

And BTW, I would suggest you to import the com dll to your application as a reference, rather than doing it the tough way using `CreateObject()`, `CreateObject()` is a recipe for failure and not a good practice if it can be avoided.
You need to add to your project a reference to the [SHDocVw.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741313.aspx), then you can simply declare the InternetExplorer object strongly typed and not hard-coded:

```
Public Class Form1 : Inherits Form
  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
      Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    ie.Navigate("http://google.com")
    ie.Visible = True
    Me.Activate()
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: If I understand the problem, his process that launches IE runs in the background, meaning whatever window he's working in (e.g. Word) loses the focus when the background process runs.  His process won't know which window to call Window.Activate on, because it won't know what window he's working on.  I agree that using a reference is better than CreateObject(), if that's an option for him.

Comment: Ok, I just suggested, but still I think using it strongly-type will be the recommended way eitherway. whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will definitely change it from create object.

Answer (score 0):

FYI using TweakUI or changing the 'ForegroundLockTimeout' Registry entry does not solve the problem. Every time you run oIE.Navigate IE will steal focus from your active window, even if oIE.Visible = False.

There is no known solution for this at the time of this writing (maybe that's why the op ended up just having to deal with it as he stated).